# How to reduce Computational Time for a small dataset?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I've been working on text detection as part of my research, focusing on various characteristics. I'm encountering a significant issue with computational time. My dataset consists of 3400 rows and 2 columns. I'm using a BERT model to train and evaluate the dataset. Currently, I'm utilizing Colab Pro as I don't have access to a GPU. Initially, for 50 epochs, it took approximately 65 hours for computational processing. I then reduced it to 20 epochs, but it's still taking an unexpectedly long time—around 24 hours—for a dataset containing only 3400 texts

Training Arguments:

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./output',
    do_train=True,
    do_eval=True,
    num_train_epochs=20,
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    warmup_steps=100,
    weight_decay=0.05,
    logging_strategy='steps',
    logging_dir='./multi-class-logs',
    logging_steps=50,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    eval_steps=50,
    save_strategy="steps",
    load_best_model_at_end=True
)
```

Is there anything here that if changed then my computation might get faster?
I am expecting changes in my code that will faster the computational time.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to worth try:

1. Smaller/Lightweight BERT Model:

   Depending on the task requirement you might be able to smaller versions of
   BERT(DistilBERT) and it has comparable accuracy.
2. Evaluate the model less frequently.

   eval_steps=100
3. Reducing Logging Frequency.

   logging_steps=100

Worth using profiler to determine which operation consumes the most time and resources.